# How do you tell where a function in Elixir is coming from?

Tags: elixir

For example, [assign](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix_live_reload/blob/master/lib/phoenix_live_reload/channel.ex#L14) isn't defined anywhere in this module. You can also see that is `use`s `Phoenix.Channel`, but that doesn't have `assign` defined anywhere either. It turns out `assign` is defined in [Phoenix.Socket](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2.1/lib/phoenix/socket.ex#L224), and the only reason I know that is because there's a macro defined in `Phoenix.Socket` called [channel](https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/v1.2.1/lib/phoenix/socket.ex#L256), which is what uses `Phoenix.LiveReload.Channel`. And apparently, somehow, that gives `Phoenix.LiveReload.Channel` the `assign` function.

How are you supposed to trace that logic other than `grep`. Like, if I were just looking at `Phoenix.LiveReload.Channel`, how would I know where `assign` came from?

Comment: One way would be to add `IO.inspect(__ENV__.functions)` to the module after all the `use`, `import`, and `require` calls, compile the package, and find ( (can also be done programatically if needed) the function in the value that's output during compilation.

Answer (score 2):

This was the response from the creator, Jose Valim:

> Elixir imports and aliases are lexical, which means that anything that appears in a module that you have not defined must have been explicitly imported in the code. So looking for use Mod or import Mod is the way to go to find from where a function comes from.
>   The only exception to this rule is the Kernel module which is imported by default.